# 'rbenv install 2.0.0-p247' fails

Tags: ruby, rbenv, archlinux

i already discussed this issue with the maintainer of ruby-build and followed his advice by googling for similar errors. i found similar ones but they do not seem to match my specific problem:

i'm trying to install ruby with `rbenv install 2.0.0-p247` (using the ruby-build plugin) on archlinux – but the command fails.

here the last 10 log lines:

```
rbconfig.rb updated
generating enc.mk
compiling dln.c
compiling encoding.c
generating prelude.c
compiling prelude.c
linking static-library libruby-static.a
verifying static-library libruby-static.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libruby-static.a] Error 1
```

i would appreciate any hints on this problem – thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out what's wrong here, the best bet is to run the Ruby installation yourself to see exactly what's amiss. ruby-build typically downloads and extracts Ruby in /tmp (it should be the same path where it also saves the log file of the failed install).

Go to that directory and run:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

To see if you get the same error. If you do, then try to re-run the command that failed again. In your case this is probably:

```
$ ranlib libruby-static.a
```

To see why it fails.

Comment: `ranlib libruby-static.a` results in `ranlib: libruby-static.a: No space left on device`. `df -h` shows that there is simply not enough memory available for the /tmp directory – my fault.